# Have two counters, each one with its own reducer and actions.js . Unable to show the count variable in a <div>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have the classic counter(plus button, minus button and the count showing) two times(counter.js and counter2.js ) . Each counter has its own reducer and actions.js

I'm using redux-logger so I can see in the console. I can tell that each counter updates its corresponding "count". However only in the console. In the actual page , I have a div to show the "count" state but it is not showing at all. This is what I'm using in counter.js and counter2.js , respectively, to show the count

```
<div>{this.props.count}</div>
```

and

```
<div>{this.props.count}</div>
```

I have reducer.js and reducer2.js which each contains respectively

```
const initialState = {
    count : 0,
    test:null
};
```

and

```
const initialState = {
    count : 0,
    test:null
};
```

again, in the console, using the redux logger, they do update properly, so I know my code is working. My issue is calling those "count" on the div

Comment: Are you using a Functional Component or Class Based?  If you are using Functional component drop the {this} keyword.

Comment: @chris56tv try to add more relevant code. The whole reducer, action and also conected component (and rendering component, if it is not the same one).

Comment: @Grant it's the class based